# VideoStream is stuck after a few seconds in javafx and opencv

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, javafx, sphinx4

I am a beginner and I am trying to make a javafx application to detect my face and speech so far everything works for a few seconds after I start the application but the videostream stops after a few seconds. Im new to multithreading is there anyway I can make the application more efficent?

```java
package com.example.oops;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.objdetect.Objdetect;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.videoio.Videoio;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class VideoController implements Initializable {
    public ImageView VideoOut;

    public ChoiceBox Choice;
    public Label TextOutput;
    private VideoCapture capture;
    private boolean capturing = false;
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        capture = new VideoCapture(0);
        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 400);
        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 200);
        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS, 20);
        if (capture.isOpened()) {
            capturing = true;
            startCapture();
            startText();

        } else {
            System.err.println("Camera not found.");
        }

    }

    public void stopCapture() {
        capturing = false;
        capture.release();
    }


    private void startText() {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                textStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error in Text Stream");
            }
        });

        }


    public void textStream() throws IOException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("./src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("./src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("./src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
        configuration.setGrammarPath("./src/main/resources/");
        configuration.setGrammarName("grammar");
        configuration.setUseGrammar(true);

        LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

        recognizer.startRecognition(true);

        SpeechResult result;
        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
            {
                SpeechResult finalResult = result;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextOutput.setText(finalResult.getHypothesis());
                    }
                });


            }
        }
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }



    public void startCapture() {
        if (capturing) {


            executor.execute(() -> {
                Mat frame = new Mat();
                while (capturing) {
                    if (capture.read(frame)) {
                        Mat newframe = detectFace(frame);
                        Image imageToShow = mat2Image(newframe);
                        updateImageView(VideoOut, imageToShow);
                    }
                    else {
                        capturing = false; // Stop capturing if there's an issue reading frames
                    }
                }
                stopCapture();
            });

        }
    }

    private Image mat2Image(Mat frame) {
        MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", frame, buffer);
        return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
    }

    private void updateImageView(ImageView view, Image image) {
        if (view != null && image != null) {
            view.setImage(image);
        }
    }

    public static Mat detectFace(Mat inputImage) {
        MatOfRect personDetected = new MatOfRect();
        CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier();
        int minFaceSize = Math.round(inputImage.rows() );
        cascadeClassifier.load("./src/main/resources/myhaar.xml");
        cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(inputImage,
                personDetected,
                1.2,
                6,
                Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
                new Size(minFaceSize* 0.2f, minFaceSize* 0.2f),
                new Size()
        );



        Rect[] personArray =  personDetected.toArray();

        for(Rect face : personArray) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(inputImage, face.tl(), face.br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2 );

           // Point labelPosition = new Point(face.tl().x, face.tl().y - 10); // Adjust the position as needed
           // Imgproc.putText(inputImage, "Jeffin", labelPosition, Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        }

        return inputImage;
    }
}
```

I tried using the ExecutorService class instead of just creating a new Thread.

Comment: Can you provide a simple working example of your app including the needed files?